# Gradle nested, multi project, shared libraries environment setup

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-studio

I have been trying to migrate from Eclipse to Android Studio for last couple of days and have experienced some problems regarding dependencies setup...

Here is basically the eclipse project dependency structure that exists now

```
- External Library 1
- External Library 2
- External Library 3
.
.
.
- External Library n
    |
    - CustomSetOfLibrariesProject (Library project with lots of custom classes, custom views, backend helper classes...)
        |
        |
        - App_Type_A_Project - (Library project, on top of which I can create different apps (App001, App002) with different names, graphics, package etc.
        |   |
        |   - App_Type_A_Package001, App_Type_A_Package002, etc. ... (Actual final Android Type_A product submitted to Google Play)
        |
        |
        - App_Type_B_Project - (Library project, on top of which I can create different apps (App001, App002) with different names, graphics, package etc.
            |
            - App_Type_B_Package001, App_Type_B_Package002, etc. ... (Actual final Android Type_B product submitted to Google Play)
```

The whole project structure includes:

'CustomSetOfLibrariesProject' - lots of custom classes, custom views, backend helper classes... This project is dependent on all of required external libs like tape, android async http

Each of the Projects is always based on 'CustomSetOfLibrariesProject' - so this is a big shared library, that already depends on some external libraries

This is the disk file structure

```
TOP DIRECTORY
    |
    - libs-android
    |   |
    |   - custom_set_of_libraries_project
    |   - external_lib_1
    |   - external_lib_2
    |
    - app_type_A_project
    - app_type_B_project
    - android-release
        |
        - app_type_A_package001
        - app_type_A_package002
        - app_type_B_package001
        - app_type_B_package002
```

I find it really hard to achieve this dependency structure in Android Studio, and obviously am experiencing 'Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.'.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is for each External Library, I create a project and maintain it separately (usually projects pulled from github and customized/bug fixes by me)

build the External Library's project to generate the .jar or .aar file. You can copy this file to your project's libs folder or link it(e.g. ln -s ../../ExternalLib/build/lib.jar ./lib.jar)

Create a Product Project, and for each App create a Module. link or copy all your external lib's jar file into libs' folder

edit each module's build.gradle file if you are using any of your external lib

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // or
    compile(name: 'externalLib1', ext: 'jar')
    compile(name: 'externalLib2', ext: 'aar')
}
```

http://oi61.tinypic.com/n4fgp4.jpg

3 level deep hierarchy:

project''s gradle: settings.gradle

```
include ':app', ':lib1', ':CustomSetOfLibrariesProject'
```

External library1: lib1.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

shared library's gradle: CustomSetOfLibrariesProject.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':lib1')
}
```

Product App's gradle: app.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':CustomSetOfLibrariesProject')
}
```

Comment: This covers just a small part of the question... It is basically 3 level deep hierarchy and external libs are not the major part of the problem.

Comment: just treat your "CustomSetOfLibrariesProject" as an external library, 
or have it as an module in your Main Product Project. and for each Product App's build.gradle add it as dependency
    compile project(':CustomSetOfLibrariesProject')

Comment: That is what I am trying to achieve, but "CustomSetOfLibrariesProject" has subprojects and somehow it won't compile.

Comment: any error log?  PS:make sure you don't have any circular dependency, and each dependency is added(check it at your Project Structure)

Comment: Dependency is PackageA001> TypeABase > CustomSetOfLibrariesProject > few different libraries
can't really change it as it would be too much work. I think the problem is that I can have only one settings.gradle and only the top project one will be valid, where I wanted to do this dependency step by step through projects like I could in eclipse...

Comment: I was able to create a 3 level deep hierarchy without any problem. just updated my answer.

Comment: Doesn't seem nested at all